# Checking out of bounds in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to check if an array location is out of bounds, what's the simplest way?

```
int[] arr;
populate(arr);
if(arr[-1] == null)
//out of bounds!
```

Would something like this work?

I'm pretty sure this can be done with a trycatch or a scanner but for just a simple small program, is there another way?

Comment: Compare it to `0`, compare it to `arr.length`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Absolutely **do not** use try-catch for this. Simply use:

```
boolean inBounds = (index >= 0) && (index < array.length);
```

Implementing the approach with try-catch would entail catching an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), which is an unchecked exception (i.e. a subclass of [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)). Such exceptions should never (or, at least, *very* rarely) be caught and dealt with. Instead, they should be prevented in the first place.

In other words, unchecked exceptions are exceptions that your program is *not expected to recover from*. Now, there can be exceptions (no pun intended) to this here and there. For instance, it has become common practice to check if a string is parable as an integer by calling `Integer.parseInt()` on it and catching the potential `NumberFormatException` (which is unchecked). This is considered OK, but always think twice before doing something like that.

Comment: Is the system in an illegal state with unpredictable results? What exactly is the harm?

Comment: I believe in most cases one should only catch unchecked exceptions when IO is involved, for instance in the case of converting a String to an Integer or check for null input from a hardware device (this often includes working with JNI). Otherwise you should avoid catching uncheck exceptions as suggested. Adding a comment to provide further context to what was suggested.

Answer (score 5):

No, that will cause an exception.

Instead, do

```
if (x < 0 || x >= arr.length) {
    //x is out of bounds!
}
```

Comment: I believe it's `x >= arr.length`

Comment: And don't forget the `()` brackets around the condition.

Comment: what if arr is empty and x is zero it will fail

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer to check if x is out of bounds: if (x < 0 || x >= arr.length). To check if it's IN bounds, we perform a simple negation: if (! (x < 0 || x >= arr.length)) -- which, after simplifying using De Morgan's Law, we obtain: if (x >= 0 && x < arr.length). Final note: Do NOT use/abuse Exceptions!

Answer (score 3):

It is better to check if the index is in range manually.

```
if(index >=0 && index < array.length){
   // in range
}
```

Exceptions which are unchecked, that is which do not require a try-catch block, should not be caught. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is one of them.

All unchecked exceptions come from `RuntimeException` class.
From this class comes the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
This is further specialized into `StringIndexOutOfBounds` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`

> RuntimeException is the superclass of those exceptions that can be
>   thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.
>   Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.